# Version 15.2 of ios on ipad changed the color of buttons on my webpage, is there a way to overcome this behaviour

Tags: html, css, ios, ipad

When I updated the IOS to 15.1 on my ipad the color of text inside the button tag has change in each of my web pages.

Is there a way to force the IOS to show the color of the text inside the button as it is on  onther browsers ad as it was before the update?

Comment: iOS 15.1 or 15.2 ? BTW , can you show an example of html code that reproduce the problem ? Like a page with one button and Color not working as intended.

Comment: IOS 15.1 .Unfortunatly no because the web pages are visibile inside our company intranet. Anyway, the big problem is that the color of the text inside the button tag has become lightblue instead of black, this in each page. This on chorme and safari as well  and only after the IOS apdate. On PC the colors of the text inside the button is as usual, black. This look trivial but because many buttons have a background different from the default lightgray the text can be difficult to read. The same problem is present in the select tag e in th browser tab.

Comment: Did you try check if it is related to clear/dark mode. There have been some changes in WebKit.

Comment: Yes i did but I do not see any difference swiching from one mode to the other.

Comment: I looks like the default color of the text in tags like button, select etc is now lightblue and not black.